# Using autofill increment

Tags: excel, vba

When I use autofill on DragDownCell1, the number 30 does not increment and increase each line. But using autofill on DragDownCell2, it adds 1 to each line.

This is a **really simplified version** of my code

```
Set DragDownCell1 = wsDest.Cells(Lastrow, "AP")
    DragDownCell1.Value = 30
        
Set DragDownCell2 = wsDest.Cells(Lastrow, "AQ")
    DragDownCell2.Value = "Net 30"
```

Then i have a for loop which fills information into each last row of my spreadsheet, at the end of the for loop I add 1 to lastrow so that it keeps adding information to the last row and doesnt overwrite itself.

```
For x = i + 1

Lastrow = Lastrow + 1

Next x

DragDownCell1.AutoFill Destination:=wsDest.Range(DragDownCell1, wsDest.Cells(Lastrow - 1, "AP")), Type:=xlFillDefault
        
DragDownCell2.AutoFill Destination:=wsDest.Range(DragDownCell2, wsDest.Cells(Lastrow - 1, "AQ")), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Is it possible to change whether or not the value increments or not and if so can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Change `xlFillDefault` to `xlFillSeries`?

Comment: I was always a bit confused why the default behaviour for drag n fill with numbers is copy, but with text is increment by 1. If there's not more than one cell to infer a pattern then why does it assume that?

Comment: @BigBen I don't know why but that hasn't worked, any other ideas?  